# Correct display of RTF file content in the control WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

After converting from PDF to RTF, the file correctly opens only in MS Word, but it does not open correctly in WPF RichTextBox. In my case, the pictures are moved to the beginning of the document. I noticed that after converting from PDF to RTF images are stored in shapes that have an margin relative to the beginning of the document, so the images are not displayed correctly in the WPF RichTextBox. How to convert this RTF file for correct display in WPF RichTextBox?

Comment: This question has been asked quite a bit, I'm fairly certain the other answers and questions address this question.  Also, in the future a minimal viable example is often recommended, to recreate your issue to assist you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open PDF file in RichTextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876749/open-pdf-file-in-richtextbox-in-wpf)