# Render PDF using DocumentViewer control?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, documentviewer

Is it possible to render PDF using DocumentViewer (it's WPF control) ?

If it is possible then how ? Code example or link to some code example would be appreciated. 
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with the DocumentViewer - unless you convert to XPS first.

There are a few other threads on displaying PDF in WPF:

- [Display a PDF in WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/opening-a-pdf-in-wpf-application)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/PDFViewerControl.aspx

Comment: That VB.NET control from CodeProject seems to no longer word, or at least it has problems with recent PDF (it doesn't display text with True Type (CID) font, identity-H). Anyway, I ended up using [this PDF viewer](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/pdf-xpsdocument-wpf/1001).