# Open PDF in DocumentViewer control

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf-viewer

I am creating an application in WPF. I need to open any PDF document in a document viewer in C# WPF.

Is it possible with document viewer control?

Which property should I use to set the document path?

XAML Code:

```
<DocumentViewer x:Name="dv" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792" Height="419" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

I want to open a PDF document in the DocumentViewer control.

Comment: Same question I think, probably will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/3432173/77205

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render PDF using DocumentViewer control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430177/render-pdf-using-documentviewer-control)