# open a PDF : WPF

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

I want to open a PDF file in a button click. I'll keep the PDF file within the solution/namespace of the project. Can anyone give me solution for this?

Comment: Do you want to open the PDF "inside" your application or is it ok when e.g. the Acrobat Reader starts externally and shows the PDF?

Comment: Which ever may be... i want a solution for this problem. Would be better if i could open it in my application itself

Comment: Put a link on your desktop to the PDF file and then click on it to open the file. Oh come, be serious, provide more details about what type of application you are working on and what exactly are you trying to do. Also tag your question appropriately. `.net-3.5` is too broad.

Comment: For showing a pdf file in your WPF application look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/opening-a-pdf-in-wpf-application otherwise, just run Application.Run(pdffile).

Comment: i have a wpf application. in the main form i have a button named "HELP". When the user clicks on this button a PDF file which is the user help document for the application should be opened.

Answer (score 6):

To start the standard PDF viewer you can simply start an external process:

```
Process proc = new Process( );
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( ) {
    FileName = path //put your path here
};
proc.Start( );
```

To show the file inside your application you have to use the pdf viewer as an ActiveX-component.

Comment: how will i specify the path of the file if that pdf file resides inside the solution of the project?

Comment: easier: Process.Start(pdffile);

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
private AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF axAcroPDF1;
this.axAcroPDF1 = new AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF();
this.axAcroPDF1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.axAcroPDF1.Enabled = true;
this.axAcroPDF1.Name = "axAcroPDF1";
this.axAcroPDF1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axAcroPDF1.OcxState")));
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(DownloadedFullFileName);
axAcroPDF1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

- User WPF WebBrowser control and open the pdf:
  [Link 1](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article840-working-with-webbrowser-in-wpf-.aspx), [Link 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/XMLViewer.aspx)
- User WinformsHost to host ActiveX [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/opening-a-pdf-in-wpf-application).