# WinForms - How to open and show a pdf you just saved using iTextSharp?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, pdf, c#-4.0, itext

I'm saving data as a .pdf with a program.

However, I can't figure out how to open the .pdf I have just saved, to show it to the user.

Comment: What kind of program? Web application? Windows application? Two different methods to show a saved PDF.

Comment: Windows forms application. Didn't realize it mattered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you specify a WinForm application. Here a simple way that **assumes** Acrobar Reader (or other PDF reader) are instaled on the client machine running your app.

Use the 'System.Diagnostics.Process' class to start the PDF reader. You need only pass the path to your PDF resource. ex:

`Process.Start("filename.pdf");`

There are other approaches discussed here:

[Opening a PDF in WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/opening-a-pdf-in-wpf-application)