# PDF to WPF Document

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening a PDF in WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/opening-a-pdf-in-wpf-application)

Is there a way to load a PDF into a WPF FixedDocument or FlowDocument without 3rd party components?

Comment: Yes, by parsing the PDF language yourself and building a FixedDocument manually from scratch.

Comment: If you manage to convert your PDF document into the XPS format, then you could load that into WPF natively. However, you’ll still probably need a third-party component for the conversion (unless you manually use the Microsoft XPS Document Writer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a PDF converter to generate image files for each page in the PDF file and then combine these to a `FixedDocument`.

For the PDF conversion you can use [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) (use the in-process `gsdll32.dll`). There is a GPL licensed version and a commercial version.

The drawback is that your documents are rendered during the conversion and you will not be able search the resulting `FixedDocument` or improve the quality by rendering it at a higher DPI.