# Creating print previews of documents

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, xps, print-preview

I need to create a software which will create print previews of the documents of following formats: the MS Office documents (`.doc(x)`, `.ppt(x)`, `.xls(x)`), images, `.txt` files and PDF files. I have made a working prototype using `XPS` files. So basically I do the following: I convert the office files to `.xps` using Office Automation and then I render the `.xps` documents to images. I simply create XPS files from images and `.txt` by adding text or an image to `FlowDocument`, then rendering it. But I have found out that there is no way to convert PDF to XPS fast (A document which has 600 pages takes more than 2 minutes to convert and this is totally not suitable). So I am stuck at this point. It seems that I should start over again, using the different file format. Should I rewrite my program using PDF, for example, or is there any other way to accomplish my task? And if I should use PDF, could you, please, suggest me a good PDF C# library to render previews of pages as fast as possible? I tried using **Websupergoo's ABCPdf**, but it is too slow, because it does not allow me to render the previews to `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource`, only `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, so I have to convert `Bitmap` to `BitmapSource` and it takes up a lot of time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ghostscipt to convert PDF to images. Though, I don't know why you wouldn't just use the PDF. I have used GhostScript for a number of PDF/Image manipulation tasks.

http://www.wibit.net/blog/integrating_ghostscript_c

Ghostscript will output any PDF to images to the settings you specify. I think you can use it as a DLL or as a commandline process.

Comment: Could you suggest me a good PDF .NET library for fast page rendering?

Comment: Is this WPF or winforms? This quesion may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/opening-a-pdf-in-wpf-application

Comment: The application is using WPF.