# Open PDF in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, pdf

I have followed this link - [Display a PDF in WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/opening-a-pdf-in-wpf-application) to open `PDF` in a `WPF` application:

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF)); `  // axAcroPdf1 = new AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF();
//this.axAcroPdf1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
//this.axAcroPdf1.Enabled = true;
//this.axAcroPdf1.Name = "Demo";
//this.axAcroPdf1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axAcroPdf1.OcxState")));
//axAcroPdf1.LoadFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\FileStorage\\Demo.pdf");        
// axAcroPdf1.Visible = true;
```

Got an *exception* like this:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral >culture.  Make sure "AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF.resources" was correctly embedded or linked >into assembly "AxInterop.AcroPDFLib" at compile time, or that all the satellite >assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: A couple of things I could think of:

1. You're missing the `AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF.resources` reference (hope this isn't too condescending :( )

2. The DLL is blocked. Right-click it with `explorer`, click `Properties` and click `Unblock`.