# Embed a .PDF file directly in a C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, embed

I'm trying to embed a .pdf file directly in a C# WPF application. I tried to use a webcontrol but run into problems because of active-c security stuff.

I also tried to use pdfium & moonpdf, but wasn't able to run either one of them because of built errors. Is there a simple way to embed a PDF file? Are there any good tutorials out there?

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083/display-a-pdf-in-wpf-application/55177#55177

Comment: have you tried this WPF control built around Adobe Reader's control? https://wpfpdfviewer.codeplex.com

Comment: Thank's for you're answers Yeah i tried bit, but wasn't able to get it work :/